# Subscribe to Observable based on value of BehaviorSubject

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I am having trouble wrapping my head around trying to subscribe to an observable inside a component that depends on the incoming `Input()` value. This value is, in turn, set by a `BehaviorSubject` in another service.

Basically, `activeForm` in the child component receives the value from the parent component. The parent component, in turn, gets the value from a `BehaviorSubject`. Consequently, the value is not instantaneous.

`activeForm` has a property `id`, which determines the value used for another service call, which I plan to make in the `ngOnInit` hook.

```
export class AllFilesComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatTable, { static: false }) table: MatTable<TierData>;
  dataSource: AllFilesDataSource;
  @Input() activeForm: Form;

  ngOnInit() {
    // I plan to use the value of property 'id' from activeForm to make the following:
    // but if the activeForm is not set yet, this.formId will be undefined!
    this.fileService.getDatafilesInForm(this.formId).subscribe(data => {

    }
  }
```

I am fairly confident that if I subscribe to that `activeForm` as an Observable and then call `this.fileService.getDatafilesInForm` within it, then it would work but it doesn't seem right and feels clunky; I would like a declarative approach without any anti-patterns. I'm still mastering RxJS and it's been quite challenging so any help is appreciated!

**Edit**
Parent component template

```
<div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="center" fxLayoutGap="16px" fxLayoutGap.xs="0"
  fxLayoutAlign="start stretch">

  <!-- Tree view on LHS-->
  <div fxFlex="20%">
    <div class="spinner-container" *ngIf="isTreeLoading">
      <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
    </div>
    <app-tree-view [TDataSource]="TData"></app-tree-view>
  </div>

  <div fxFlex fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="16px">
    <!-- Results table-->
    <app-all-files class="mat-elevation-z4" [activeForm]="activeForm"></app-all-files>

    <!-- GOOGLE MAP code removed as not relevant to question-->


  </div>
</div>
```

Parent component TS:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private formService: FormService) {
    this.activeForm = null;
    this.isTreeLoading = true;
    this.TData = [{ name: 'loading structure...' }];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formId = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.subscriptions = this.formService.currentForm.subscribe(response => {
      this.activeForm = response;
      if (this.activeForm) {
        this.TData = this.formService.generateTreeStructure(this.activeForm);
        this.isTreeLoading = false;
      } 
      else {
        // this call to the service updates the BehaviorSubject
        this.formService.getSingleFormFromAPI(this.formId);        
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: use ngOnChange instead of ngOnInit if you relay on values that will be changed during the lifetime of your component also remember to clean up any subscription if they were established in earlier call of ngOnChange

Comment: Can you please post the parent component code/template code?

Comment: @user2216584 posted. Please have a look.

Comment: In your AllFilesCompnent when you say this.formId you mean this.activeForm.formId, is that correct? As I do not see any formId property directly on AllFilesComponnent?

Comment: @user2216584 No. The way it's implemented is, when you navigate to route '/forms/:id', the component takes the route param of id, and then checks if a currently active Form exists. if not, it will call the service to get a form and the service will call .next() on the BehaviorSubject to publish to all subscribers. When activeForm is set in this parent, then the child also gets it.

Comment: @user2216584 all good now. Thanks for your effort. Xesenix has pointed out that ngOnChanges lifecycle method. Looking at this at 4 am and that clearly did not come up to me as obvious at all.